# How do I restrict the user to number only inputs?

Tags: c++, numbers, codeblocks

Ok, so basically I am having to make a basic program for a club at my school. I am trying to make it to where when the user inputs something that is not a number, it has an error message and loops back around to ask for the number again. This is not it exactly, but something I threw together real quick as an example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main() { 
int a;
int b;

do{
cout << "Welcome to the equalizer. Please enter a number." << endl; 
cin >> a;

cout << endl << "Ok, now I need another number." << endl;
cin >> b; //if a number is not entered, I need an error message and a loop back to the request for the number.
if(a>b){
cout << a << " is greater than " << b << endl;

      }
if(b>a){
cout << b << " is greater than " << a << endl;

      }
if(b=a){
cout << a << " is equal to " << b << endl;

      }
cout << "restart? Enter Y if yes, or enter anything else to close." << endl;
cin >> c;

}while(c=="y" || c=="Y");

return 0;
```

Comment: Just test the result of the `cin >> a` operation. Like `if(!(cin >> a)) { /* invalid input, clean up stream state and resume */ }`

Comment: Universal checked-input algorithm: read a line of text; check it for bad characters; if it’s okay, use it, otherwise show an error message; repeat until done.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I got it right, you can use something like "isdigit('char')". Do not forget to include "ctype.h".
In your code it will be something like:

```
if (!isdigit(c))
  continue;
```

If the number may be a string like "1232321" then you may need to iterate through that string checking each char and exit if it is not...

```
bool error = false;    
for (int i = 0; i < c.length(); i ++)
    {
       if (!isdigit(c[i]))
       {
          error = true;
          break;
       }
    }
```

Hope, this helps.

P.S. Of course, "a" and "b" in your example should be of type string or char...